# Download file button return nothing after has been clicked?

Tags: php, sql

I have created an upload page to upload files then it changes its name after the upload button clicked
this all happened in the back end "admin site"
in the front end i have provided this code :

```
 <?php foreach ($files as $file): ?>
 <div class='form-group'>
   <p><a href="contact.php?fn=<?php echo $file['file_id'] ?>">Click here to download the file</a></p>
 </div>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

once the user click on the link file should be downloaded based in the code below:

```
//fetch all recorders in the table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM policy";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$files = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//get the id number from the request 

if (isset($_GET['fn'])) {
    $id = $_GET['fn'];
// fetch file to download from database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM policy WHERE file_id=?";
$stmt= mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"i",$id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
$file=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

/* modify the file name by adding extension because the file when uploaded in database it 
uploaded without extension name so it can match the recorders in uploading folder  */
 $filename=$file['name'].'.pdf';
$filepath = 'uploads/' .$filename;

if (file_exists($filepath)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filepath));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('uploads/' . $filename));
   
    readfile('uploads/' . $filename);

    // Now update downloads count
    $newCount = $file['downloads'] + 1;
    $updateQuery = "UPDATE policy SET downloads=$newCount WHERE file_id=$id";
    mysqli_query($conn, $updateQuery);
    exit;
}

}
```

but what has happened nothing  it only refreshes the page without download anything

I hope someone helps me with this problem.